# How to re-order pages en-masse

Tags: pages, sort

The site I'm working on has a few thousand pages, each of which is an address listing. I need them sorted by a) street name, and b) address number. I can go through each individually and change the order# but that gets old after the first 100, and I've got 9000+ to work through.

Is there any way to sort these in that particular order quickly?

Edit: trying to get the order sorted in both front and back ends.

Comment: Where is the street name and address number stored? If this info is stored in post meta, what are the keys? Are you trying to achieve this on the front end, or back end, or both? At any rate, menu order is probably not the best way to go here.

Comment: @DaveRomsey I'm not sure the pages have any post meta attached, the posts have been aggregated over a couple years and now I'm supposed to clean them up. I'm trying to get them ordered on both front and back end, so it's easily readable by both site users and by the admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>First, the approach for setting up a sorting algorithm depends on where/how those street name and address numbers are stored. Single line in a `meta_key`, two separate `meta_key` entries, dumped into content for some reason, etc. etc. etc.</s>

OP is dealing with addresses stored as `post_title` values. So below assumes string like:

*1234 Main Street*

The rest of it, matching and updating the page `menu_order` key is fairly straightforward.

Perhaps a process like this:

- from `init` hook:

  [`order_pages_by_values()`]
- get an array of page objects:

  [`$pages = get_pages_wrapper();`]
- for each page object, pass the ID to a function that gets number/street values:

  1) [`$addresses = extract_and_conflate_address( $pages );`]

  2) [`$number = get_address_number( $page->ID );`]

  3) [`$street = get_address_street( $page->ID );`]

  4) [
    `$split = explode( ' ', $address, 2 );
    if ( $value === 'number' ) {
      $return = $split[0];
    }
    elseif ( $value === 'street' ) {
      $return = $split[1];
    }`]
- add number and street values to array as `key => value`, i.e. `numeric => street`:

  [`$address_k_v[$number] = $street;`]
- <s>sort the values and then keys of that array</s>
- create a multi-dimensional array of `street => array ( numeric, )`

  1) [`$flatten_array = sort_values_and_keys_and_flatten( $addresses )`]

  2) [

  ```
  foreach( $array as $n => $s ) {


      if ( array_key_exists( $s, $multi_array ) ) {
          $multi_array[$s][] = $n;
      }
      else {
           $multi_array[$s] = array( $n );
       }
    }
  ```

  ]
- sort the `street` keys of outer array, then for each `street`, sort the inner numeric values array

  1) [`ksort($multi_array);`]

  2) [`foreach ($multi_array as $street => $numbers_array ) {
        asort($numbers_array);`]
- <s>for each (now sorted) `number => street` entry, make that a string of `number-street`, and add it to a new array</s>
- for each (now sorted) `street => array ( numeric )` (the inner array), add a string of `number-street` to a new array:

  [
          `foreach( $numbers_array as $na ) {
          $flatten_array[] = $na .'-'. $street;`]
- for each page object, get the number and the street again, this time using them to create a string of `numberic-street`:

  ```
  $number = get_address_number( $page->ID );
  $street = get_address_street( $page->ID ); 

  $match_string = $number . '-' . $street;`
  ```
- search the array of sorted `numberic-street` strings for this `numberic-street` string, returning the index number to set `$menu_order`:

  [`$menu_order = array_search( $match_string, $flatten_array );`]
- create args array for post with `ID => page->ID` and `menu_order => index number`:

  ```
  $update_post_args = array( 'ID'         => $page->ID,
                             'menu_order' => $menu_order
                          );
  ```
- update post with those args:

  [`wp_update_post( $update_post_args )`]

---

It's impossible to guess a solution without where those address fields are stored, but I've included a possible approach using `explode` on `post_title` in case that's part of your current nightmare. ;)

The below is just an example of a possible process to start with of course, test it before giving it a full go. I'd probably wrap it all in a class of a plugin.

```
add_action( 'init', 'order_pages_by_values' );


function get_pages_wrapper() {
    $args = array( 'post_type'   => 'page',
                   'post_status' => 'publish'
                 );
    $pages = get_pages( $args );

    return $pages;
}


function extract_and_conflate_address( $pages ) {
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $number = get_address_number( $page->ID ); //depends on where value is stored
        $street = get_address_street( $page->ID ); //depends on where value is store

        $address_k_v[$number] = $street;
   }
   return $address_k_v;
}
//old version, several issues with this.
 // First, it is more of a re-sort, ignoring previously sorted items.
 /// Second, it cannot preserve instances where same post box address (1234) for different street would overwrite previous entry.
 /* function sort_values_and_keys( &$array, $valrev = false, $keyrev = false ) {
    //adopted from http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php#80798
    if ( $valrev ) { 

        arsort( $array );

    } else { 

        asort( $array );

    }

    $vals   = array_count_values( $array );
    $i      = 0;

    foreach ( $vals AS $val => $num ) {

        $first = array_splice( $array, 0, $i );

        $tmp   = array_splice( $array, 0, $num );

        if ( $keyrev ) { 

            krsort( $tmp ); 

        } else { 

            ksort( $tmp ); 
        }

        $array  = array_merge( $first, $tmp, $array );

        unset( $tmp );

        $i      = $num;
    }
} */

//Here we are creating a multidimensional array with the outer being Street
// and inner being an array of corresponding numerical post addresses.

function sort_values_and_keys_and_flatten( $array ) {
    //need array declared already for conditional inside foreach   
    $multi_array = array(); 

    foreach( $array as $n => $s ) {

       //makes sure Street doesn't exist yet. If it does, append, if not add.
        if ( array_key_exists( $s, $multi_array ) ) {
            $multi_array[$s][] = $n;
        }
        else {
             $multi_array[$s] = array( $n );
         }
    }

    //sort the street names
    ksort($multi_array);

    foreach ($multi_array as $street => $numbers_array ) {

        //sort the numerical addresses
        asort($numbers_array);

        //build $flatten_array
        foreach( $numbers_array as $na ) {

            $flatten_array[] = $na .'-'. $street;
        }
    }

    return $flatten_array;
 }



function order_pages_by_values() {

    $pages     = get_pages_wrapper();

    $addresses = extract_and_conflate_address( $pages );

   /**
     Replacing these lines with new sort function and setting $flatten to its return
    sort_values_and_keys( $addresses );

    foreach ( $addresses as $number => $street ) {

        $flatten_array[] = $number . '-' . $street;
    }
  */

    $flatten_array = sort_values_and_keys_and_flatten( $addresses );         

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {

        $number = get_address_number( $page->ID ); //depends on where value is stored
        $street = get_address_street( $page->ID ); //depends on where value is stored

        $match_string = $number . '-' . $street;

        $menu_order = array_search( $match_string, $flatten_array );

        $update_post_args = array( 'ID'         => $page->ID,
                                   'menu_order' => $menu_order
                                );

        wp_update_post( $update_post_args );
    }

}

function get_address_number( $id ) {
    //assuming post_meta key of 'address_number'
    //$number = get_post_meta( $id, 'address_number', true ); 

    //assuming all addresses have format 1234 Main Street and saved as post title
    $number = extract_address( get_the_title( $id ), 'number' );
    return $number;
}
function get_address_street( $id ) {
    //assumes post_meta key of 'address_street'
    //$street = get_post_meta( $id, 'address_street', true ); 

    //assuming all addresses have format 1234 Main Street and saved as post title
    $street = extract_address( get_the_title( $id ), 'street' );
    return $street;
}
function extract_address( $address, $value ) {

    $split = explode( ' ', $address, 2 );
    if ( $value === 'number' ) {
        $return = $split[0];
    }
    elseif ( $value === 'street' ) {
        $return = $split[1];
    }

    return $return;
}
```

### Update

I updated the code block above, but below is a quick test sample of the sorting function. I can't say how economical it is, but it is working on my end.
Since it is returning the value needed for `$flatten_array` in the previous version, note above that I have removed those lines from `order_pages_by_value()`

**Here is the testable code sample for the sort:**

```
//array as would be returned by extract_and_conflate_addresses()
$the_array = array( 
            '1234'      => 'Main Street',
            '100'       => 'Avenue Road',
            '105'       => 'Avenue Road',
            '106'       => 'Avenue Road',
            '106a'      => 'Avenue Road',
            '107'       => 'Avenue Road',
            '103'       => 'Front Street',
            '42'        => '5 Lane',
            '42000'     => 'B Street',
    );


function sort_values_and_keys_and_flatten( $array ) {

    //need array declared already for conditional inside foreach   
    $multi_array = array(); 

    foreach( $array as $n => $s ) {

        //makes sure Street doesn't exist yet. If it does, append, if not add.
        if ( array_key_exists( $s, $multi_array ) ) {
            $multi_array[$s][] = $n;

        }
        else {
             $multi_array[$s] = array( $n );
         }

    }

    //sort the street names
    ksort($multi_array);

    foreach ($multi_array as $street => $numbers_array ) {

        //sort the numerical addresses
        asort($numbers_array);

        //build $flatten_array
        foreach( $numbers_array as $na ) {

            $flatten_array[] = $na .'-'. $street;
        }

    }

    return $flatten_array;

}

$test = sort_values_and_keys_and_flatten( $the_array );
print_r($test);
```

**That should yield:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42-5 Lane
    [1] => 100-Avenue Road
    [2] => 105-Avenue Road
    [3] => 106-Avenue Road
    [4] => 106a-Avenue Road
    [5] => 107-Avenue Road
    [6] => 42000-B Street
    [7] => 103-Front Street
    [8] => 1234-Main Street
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure no post_meta was even made for these pages, so I'm likely drawing from only the page titles.

Comment: Consulted on similar not too long ago (300k+ posts, titled by what should be meta). Somewhere over half way through the format was different as well (new users, I assume). Setting it up to run batches and print the results 1000 or so at a time allowed us to catch it. Just an added fyi.

Comment: This seems to be ordering by street number (eg, all addresses starting with 1***) as opposed to by street name alphabetically and then by street number.

Did I mess up my implementation?

Comment: hmmm... well the idea was to make them a `key => value` in an array of `street number => street name`, then `sort_values_and_keys()` uses `asort` to sort by value (street name) and then `ksort()` to sort by key (street number). I wonder if it needs an `array_flip()` first, to sort all street numbers, then sort that sorted array by street name... see if that maintains the grouping. basically keying by street name and making the number the value.

Comment: Adding an array flip made no difference to the eventual output. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Apparently the first array_merge replaces all the address numbers that had previously been the keys to which the street addresses were keyed to with 0, 1, 2, and so on.

Comment: Actually it's the array_splice that is removing all address numbers. still weird.

Comment: I think i have another way to do this sort that may work. I'll update here in a few

Comment: I have updated with what looks like a working sort method. I'll clean up full code block and add some points to the answer in a few.